# python if statement satisfied, don't continue script

Tags: python

I am trying to get my script to print "ERROR" if a = 0. 
When running the script below, if I enter a as 0 I do get the message "error" but it also executes the rest of the script.

How can I get the script to only print "ERROR" if my condition is satisfied?

```
def print_num(a, b, c):

    if a == 0:
        print('ERROR')   

    print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Use an `else` for the rest of your function or simply `return` after printing the error message.

Comment: To take your question literally then just replace print('ERROR') with exit('ERROR'). It is however bad practice with errors.

Answer (score 4):

```
def print_num(a, b, c):

    if a == 0:
        raise ValueError('ERROR: a must not be zero')

    print(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like visibleman's solution but it would also work with an assert which is one less line and a bit cleaner

```
def print_num(a, b, c):
    assert a != 0

    print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: For something that fits a simple test (like a==0), I think you are right, an assert is cleaner from a developer standpoint. Raising is a more general solution, and allows you to make the error a bit more descriptive to the end user.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I only use raise myself. Another advantage with raising is that you can raise different errors to catch whereas assert only raises an AssertError.

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_num(a, b, c):

    if a == 0:
        print('ERROR')  
        return 

    print(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an else to the code. Like so:

```
def print_num(a, b, c):

    if a == 0:
        print('ERROR')   
    else:
        print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: The OP said they want the code to halt after the error. This code will continue to run from after the if else statement.